# Uniform convergence of a sequence of functions?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

**let $f_n: R \rightarrow R$ be a sequence of continuous functions which converge uniformly to $f: R \rightarrow R$. Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence of real numbers which converges to $x \in R$. Show that $f_n(x_n) \rightarrow f(x)$.**

So far this is my attempt at a solution but I wonder whether I can provide a shorter or more insightful proof:

1) $|f_n(x_n)-f(x)| \leq |f_n(x_n)-f_n(x)| + |f_n(x)-f(x)|$ and I argue that we can show that the expression on the right approaches zero as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

It's given that $\lim_{n \to +\infty}|f_n(x)-f(x)| = 0$ since $f_n \rightarrow f$ uniformly.

2) $\forall n, f_n(x)$ is continuous so $\forall \epsilon > 0 \exists \delta > 0, |f_n(x_n)-f_n(x)|<\epsilon \text{ when } |x_n-x|<\delta$.

Clearly, $\lim_{n \to +\infty}|f_n(x)-f_n(x)| = 0$ since $\lim_{n \to +\infty}|x_n-x| = 0$.

Q.E.D.

Comment: I think your proof would still go through if you had only pointwise convergence, which means it is not correct (since the result is false if you have only pointwise convergence).

Comment: notice that $\delta$ depends on $f_n$. It is easier to split $f_n(x_n) - f(x)$ into $f_n(x_n) - f(x_n) + f(x_n) - f(x)$ and remember that $f$ is continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In step 2, your choice of $\delta$ will depend on $n$ since it depends on the function. You would need some form of "equicontinuity" to make the argument valid. It is easily corrected, though. Use the triangle inequality to write $$|f_n(x_n) - f(x)| \le |f_n(x_n) - f(x_n)| + |f(x_n) - f(x)|.$$ Uniform convergence will take care of the first term, continuity the second term.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\varepsilon>0$. We want to show that for any such $\varepsilon$, there is an $N$ so that for every $n>N$, $\lvert f_n(x_n)-f(x) \rvert < \varepsilon$.

The triangle inequality gives
$$ \lvert f_n(x_n)-f(x) \rvert \leqslant \lvert f_n(x_n)-f(x_n) \rvert + \lvert f(x_n)-f(x) \rvert $$

For the first term, you have to say that because the convergence is uniform, you can choose $N$ *independent of $x_n$* so that
$$\lvert f_n(x_n)-f(x_n) \rvert < \varepsilon/2 \tag{1}$$
for every $n>N$.

For the second term, $f$ is a limit of a uniformly convergent set of functions, so it is continuous. Therefore there is a $\delta>0$ so that $\lvert f(y)-f(x) \rvert< \varepsilon/2$ whenever $\lvert y-x \rvert < \delta$. Next, the sequence $x_n$ converges to $x$, so there is an $M>0$ such that $\lvert x_n-x \rvert< \delta$ for every $n>M$. Hence for every $n>M$,
$$\lvert f(x_n)-f(x) \rvert < \varepsilon/2. \tag{2} $$

Now let $K=\max{\{N,M\}}$. For any $n>K$, both (1) and (2) hold, and so
$$ \lvert f_n(x_n)-f(x) \rvert < \varepsilon/2+\varepsilon/2=\varepsilon. $$

Answer (score 0):

given $f_n \to f$ uniformly 
so, for $\epsilon > 0,$ $ \exists n_1 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n > n_1$,
$|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon , \forall x$ in particular for $x_n$ again uniform convergence implies $f$ is continuous so $f(x_n) \to f(x) \implies \exists n_2\in \mathbb{N} | \forall n>n_2 ,|f(x_n)-f(x)|<\epsilon$ now the conclusion follows using triangle inequality